# Ubuntu 18.04 not boots in normal mode

Tags: boot, 18.04

Ubuntu gets stuck normal mode but in recovery works well, please help me
Any help is appreciated

(my pc: hp 240 G3 notebook pc)
EDIT : I tried booting a previous kernel but in the bootscreen i heard two beeps and now gets stuck again

Comment: Hit the escape key during normal boot.  See what is the problem or where it gets stuck.

Comment: It gets stuck in bootscreen